# Inserting additional &nbsp; into menu item text

Tags: menus

I'd like a specific menu item to have more spaces between words.

**For example:**
Word Word

**Needs to be:**
Word      Word

In the menu editor, WP strips-out any additional spaces added with the spacebar or using the HTML code `&nbsp;`.

What's the next most efficient method?

Comment: You could achieve this with CSS, using the [`word-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing) property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously I assumed WP would strip HTML, so I never tried it.

The HTML below works like a charm, using the WP menu editor:

`Word <span style="margin-left: 20px;"> </span> Word`

(however, inputting `&nbsp;` didn't)

Alternatively, the CSS trick mentioned by Jacob and Linda would work well too:

`word-spacing: 3px;`

My menu item actually has 4 words, and I just needed to increase the middle spacing.

In the end, it's nice avoiding a PHP function or JS client-side. I just wonder is there any issue down the line having HTML in my menu title. Other than my menu rendering in the page layout, I can't think of where else I may output the menu items to.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options in the wp_nav_menu function is whether to preserve whitespace.  The default is that it’s preserved, but perhaps your theme has it set to discard?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/
'item_spacing'
(string) Whether to preserve whitespace within the menu's HTML. Accepts 'preserve' or 'discard'. Default 'preserve'.

You could also add a CSS class to just that one menu item and use the word-spacing property to give the appearance of more spaces: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing

Comment: I think item_spacing and white-space have more to do with <li> separation rather than actual word separation within menu item text.